# pandas - repalce a key's value of a dictionary column with another column

Tags: python, pandas

In pandas, I have 2 columns, one of which is a dictionary and the other is a numerical column.

When the dictionary column is not null, is there a time efficient way to replace the value of a particular key with the value of the second column?

```
df=pd.DataFrame(zip([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32],
              [{'m':34, 'n':42},None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,
                {'m':54, 'n':24},None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None],
              [{'m':1, 'n':42},None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,
                {'m':17, 'n':24},None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None]      
              ), columns= ['A','B','C'])
```

As in the above example, when the dictionary column is not null, the value of the key 'm' is replaced by the value in column A.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply only on the relevant rows:

```
mask = df['C'].notnull()
df.loc[mask, 'C'] = df[mask].apply(lambda r: dict(r['C'], m=r['A']), axis=1)
```

You can make it faster with `raw`. Just make sure the structure of the columns is the same, as you use indices instead.

```
df.loc[mask, 'C'] = df[mask].apply(lambda r: dict(r[2], m=r[0]), axis=1, raw=True)
```

Result:

```
     A                   B                   C
0    1  {'m': 34, 'n': 42}   {'m': 1, 'n': 42}
1    2                None                None
2    3                None                None
3    4                None                None
4    5                None                None
5    6                None                None
6    7                None                None
7    8                None                None
8    9                None                None
9   10                None                None
10  11                None                None
11  12                None                None
12  13                None                None
13  14                None                None
14  15                None                None
15  16                None                None
16  17  {'m': 54, 'n': 24}  {'m': 17, 'n': 24}
17  18                None                None
18  19                None                None
19  20                None                None
20  21                None                None
21  22                None                None
22  23                None                None
23  24                None                None
24  25                None                None
25  26                None                None
26  27                None                None
27  28                None                None
28  29                None                None
29  30                None                None
30  31                None                None
31  32                None                None
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked. can you please tell me why the m in the dict function above is not wrapped in quotes and used without them. When I use 'm'=r['A'] I get an error.

Comment: @tjt I create a dictionary using [`dict()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict) with keyword (named) arguments, which are not strings but parameter names. Just like`axis=1` in `pd.apply`.

Answer (score 1):

Drop the null values, then `zip` the columns `A` and `B` inside a list comprehension and update the dictionaries

```
s = df.dropna(subset='B')
df.loc[s.index, 'C'] = [{**d, 'm': a} for a, d in zip(s['A'], s['B'])]
```

Result

```
     A                   B                   C
0    1  {'m': 34, 'n': 42}   {'m': 1, 'n': 42}
1    2                None                None
2    3                None                None
3    4                None                None
4    5                None                None
5    6                None                None
6    7                None                None
7    8                None                None
8    9                None                None
9   10                None                None
10  11                None                None
11  12                None                None
12  13                None                None
13  14                None                None
14  15                None                None
15  16                None                None
16  17  {'m': 54, 'n': 24}  {'m': 17, 'n': 24}
17  18                None                None
18  19                None                None
19  20                None                None
20  21                None                None
21  22                None                None
22  23                None                None
23  24                None                None
24  25                None                None
25  26                None                None
26  27                None                None
27  28                None                None
28  29                None                None
29  30                None                None
30  31                None                None
31  32                None                None
```